# Get the id of the button that opened a modal when using data-target

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I've searched many posts for an answer to this but couldn't find one. I'm spitting out records in a table and have an edit button on each row that will open a Bootstrap modal for editing. To get the data to populate the modal I need the id of the record, which is part of the button element's id:

```
<button id="btnEdit_#rsList.timID#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##editModal">Edit</button>
```

So if the button I click is on the row for record id 19, the button id will be btnEdit_19. Note this is running under ColdFusion, which is why you see the syntax above. My question is how can I get the button id in this event:

```
        $('#editModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            console.log($(e.relatedTarget));
        });
```

This is what shows in the console for $(e.relatedTarget):

```
0: <button id="btnEdit_19" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">​
context: <button id="btnEdit_19" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
length: 1
```

I'm not showing it fully expanded; context has a bunch of properties under it, one of which is the button id. However, I don't know how to pull that out of there or if its even possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
e.relatedTarget.id
```

according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget) ?

Comment: thank you! I guess I was looking in the wrong places for documentation. console.log(e.relatedTarget.id); will show what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help when I can